# Visual Studio replacing '</' with '<!--/-->/' in XMLDocs

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Recently any time I type the string `</` in a block of XML docs within Visual Studio, it is immediately replaced with `<!--/-->/`.

I have tried disabling every add-on that could possibly be causing this and the behavior still exists. I've done my best to search the settings for anything remotely related but have come up empty on that front as well.

Has anyone encountered this before and figured out how to disable it?  I can't even understand how the replacement value `<!--/-->/` is useful in any circumstance in the first place.

Comment: what is the file extension?

Comment: @mcNets .cs, but it only occurs in the XMLDocs section.  e.g. if I type it in a normal `//` comment or string literal, the replacement doesn't happen.  But when I'm on a line that begins `///`, it is replaced as soon as I type it.

Comment: !-- it's the first intellisense option when you press < seems like vs doesn't recognize </

Comment: @mcnets good point, that makes sense.  I just found the extension responsible for it.  I will open an issue and mention that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed an extension.

The extension that was responsible for this was **SHFB (Sandcastle Help File Builder)**.  As soon as I removed the extension and restarted VS the problem stopped occurring.

Update:  I logged an [issue](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues/361) with the project. There is also a workaround that does not involve uninstalling the extension:

> For the time being you can use Tools | Options, go to the Sandcastle Help File Builder category, and uncheck the "Enable extended XML comments completion options" checkbox. That'll turn off the additional completion options related to that feature. Just close and reopen any files and it'll take effect.